# Is destructuring a heap (taking down a heap) also O(n) like building a heap? If so, can the selection problem be solved by this method in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

If we can build up a heap with time O(n), can we take down a heap also by O(n)? (by delete-max repeatedly).

Intuitively, it may feel it is, because it is like the reverse of build it up.

([Building a heap can be O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) -- in Wikipedia).

If building a heap is O(n) in the worst case, including the numbers are all adding by ascending order, then taking the heap down is exactly the "reverse in time" operation, and it is O(n), but this may not be the "worst case" of taking it down.

If taking down a heap is really O(n), can't the selection problem be solved by building a heap, and then taking it down (k - 1) time, to find the kth max number?

Comment: Taking down the heap is not really the reverse of heapify, it is the reverse of starting with an empty heap and adding elements one by one. Both of these are n log n

Comment: @MatthewC building a heap is really O(n). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap

Comment: What do you mean by "take down"? Note that building heaps in linear time is _not_ accomplished by repeated "push".

Comment: @nonpolarity That is heapify (makeHeap, or whatever you like to call the process of transforming an array into a heap).

Answer (score 2):

Delete-max is $O(\log n)$, so you have $O(n) + k O(\log n)$ which is $O(n)$ for fixed $k$. But if $k$ is not fixed, it can be up to $\frac{n}{2}$ (if it's greater, just use a min-heap instead of a max-heap), and  $O(n) + \frac{n}{2} O(\log n) = O(n \log n)$.

In fact, if there was some tricky way to do what you want, you would solve sorting in $O(n)$, not just selection, which is known to be impossible.

Comment: that's true... I "accidentally" solved the sorting problem with a O(n) method

Comment: that's interesting... I usually take a shorter time taking my Mac Mini apart than to re-assemble it

Answer (score 1):

Building a heap is O(n).

Taking the first item from a heap and then re-arranging things so it is a heap again is O (log n), and since you need to do this n time is O (n log n).

Of course you can just take one element of the heap after the other in O(n), but they won't be in sorted order. And building a heap can be done in O(n) because you add n/2 items to the lowest level of the heap when it has height 1, n/4 to the second lowest level of the heap when it has height 2, n/8 when it has height 3, and so on. And n/2 * 1 + n/4 * 2 + n/8 * 3 ... < n.

Comment: I guess you are saying there is no smart way (known) to take it down so that it is O(n)

Comment: @nonopolarity You are assuming that there is a way to take it down in $O(n)$ because you can build it in $O(n)$. Just as the build operation requires you to have all $n$ elements on hand to create the heap, you can delete the heap in $O(n)$ time but only if you are deleting all $n$ elements as well.

Comment: @Throckmorton is it true that by the same argument, then it could sound like you have to build the heap by O(n log n)?

Comment: If you are building the heap by inserting elements one at a time, then it is $O(n\log n)$

Comment: "I guess you are saying there is no smart way (known) to take it down so that it is O(n) " You can take it down in O(1); just ignore the argument and return the empty heap. This won't help you with the selection problem, of course.

Comment: This answer is bad: with the same reasoning, we can argue that building a heap takes $\Omega( n \log n)$ time, which we know to be false.